# Line feed leaving extra space at end of line in XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic, carriage-return, linefeed

I have an application where I create a .csv file and then create a .xlsx file from the .csv file. The problem I am having now is that the end of rows in the .csv have a trailing space. My database is in MarkLogic and I am using a custom REST endpoint to create this. The code where I create the .csv file is:

```
document{($header-row,for $each in $data-rows return fn:concat('&#13;&#10;',$each))}
```

I pass in the header row then pass each data row with a carriage return and a line feed at the beginning. I do this to put the cr/lf at the end of the header and then each of the other lines except for the last one. I know my data rows do not have the space at the end. I have tried to normalize the space around $each and the extra space is still present. It seems to be tied to the line feed. Any suggestions on getting rid of that space?

Example of current output:

```
Name,Email,Phone 

Bill,bill@company.com,999-999-9999 

Steve,steve@company.com,999-999-9999 

Bob,bob@company.com,999-999-9999 

. . .
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a document that is `text()` node from a sequence of strings. When those are combined to create a single `text()`, they will be separated by a space. For instance, this:

```
text{("a","b","c")}
```

will produce this:

```
"a b c"
```

Change your code to use [`string-join()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string-join) to join your `$header-row` and sequence of `$data-rows` string values with the `&#13;&#10;` separator:

```
document{ string-join(($header-row, $data-rows), "&#13;&#10;") }
```

Comment: After applying this code change I am still seeing the extra space at the end of rows. What is interesting and it may have done this before, but it contains a space on columns that end in a string. However, if the row ends in an int it doesn't have the space. For example, if the phone number is 8888888888 it doesn't have the space but a row that ends with 888-888-8888 contains the space. Could I have a different problem?

Comment: Try with just the &#10; line feed instead of CRLF, or even a single character like *, just to see if/when/where the extra spaces are. Also try wrapping leading/trailing character, like quotes around your column values to verify they don’t contain those extra spaces